# How can I use the String variable transferred as the command parameter to a instance of another class in Java?

Tags: java

How can I use the String variable transferred as the command parameter to a instance of another class in Java?

Like this:

```
public class NBody {
    public static void main(double T, double dt, String filename) {
        In filename = new In();
        filename.readInt();
    }
}
```

It notified as:

> NBody.java:3: filename is already defined in
>   main(double,double,java.lang.String)      In filename = new In();

Comment: what exactly do you want?

Comment: You can't. Why would you *want* to?

Comment: you can get command parameter from the "args" variable in public static void main(string[] args){....}, then you can pass the parameter to whatever class you want..

Comment: You can't. If you want to map an Obbject to a String. Think about using a HashMap<String, In>

Comment: you have two different variables with the same name - <filename>, that's why the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is define multiple variables which have the same name, so it is impossible. Imagine if it was possible, how would java runtime know which one you reference?

However if what you want is reference a variable which name's given as command line argument. You can use Reflection.

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
        Field staticFieldMInt = Custom.class.getField("mInt"); // this can be argument
        Integer mInt = (Integer) staticFieldMInt.get(null); // null because it is a class property.
        System.out.println(mInt); // prints 10
    }
}

public class Custom {
    public static Integer mInt = 10; // this could be any type
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use runtime information (the content of a variable) to determine the *name* of a local variable. Variable names are a compile-time thing, not a runtime thing.